# How to convert list<int> to binary and save as bin file?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of ints and I need to convert it and save as binary file.
I have no idea how to achieve this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If your `List<int>` is a list of *bytes*, use [`File.writeAsBytes`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/File/writeAsBytes.html).

Comment: it is not list of bytes yet :(

Comment: how can i convert it?

Comment: Then what is it?  Is it a list of 64-bit values? 32-bit values? 16-bit values?  Something else? Where did it come from?  Can you provide an example or your input data and of what bytes you want written to the file?

Comment: example: [3, 0, 0, 22, 5, 30, 15, 66, 140, 159, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: That looks like a list of byte values.  Why can't you use `File.writeAsBytes`?

Answer (score -1):

```
final File file = File.fromRawPath(Uint8List uint8List);
```

If you have a List that represents a list of 8-bit bytes and want to write it to a file, you can simply use File.writeAsBytes.

Comment: `File.fromRawPath` doesn't *write* a file, and the `Uint8List` it takes as an argument is for the filename, not for its contents.